# array list not keeping data

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to view data from firebase to a RecyclerView
but nothing is shown and the arraylist shown to be empty outside onDataChange function

```
public class UsersView extends Fragment {
        FirebaseDatabase mFirebaseDatabase;
        DatabaseReference myRef;
        static final String TAG = "9469849848347903847";
        ArrayList mUsers;
        private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
        private RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;
        private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;

        @Nullable
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, 
@Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.users_view, 
container, false);
            mFirebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
            myRef = mFirebaseDatabase.getReference("Users");
            mRecyclerView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
            mRecyclerView.hasFixedSize();
            mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
            mUsers = new ArrayList();
            myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                    Log.e("Count ", "" + snapshot.getChildrenCount());
                    for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : 
snapshot.getChildren()) {
                        User user = postSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
                        mUsers.add(user);


                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "failed");
                }
            });
            Log.i(TAG,String.valueOf(mUsers.isEmpty()));
            mAdapter = new ExampleAdapter(mUsers);
            mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
            mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);


            return rootView;
        }
    }
```

but when i moved this code inside onDataChange every thing worked fine:

```
mAdapter = new ExampleAdapter(mUsers);
mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

Comment: (1) The code of `ExampleAdapter` is missing. (2) An adapter must be `notify`ied of changes of containing data.

Comment: Call mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); after passing arraylist to the adapter.

Comment: i did not post it here as i said everything worked fine when initialization is moved to the onDataChange method

Comment: If e.g. `ExampleAdapter` would create a copy of `mUsers`, the code would work inside `onDataChange` but could never work correctly in general, e.g. on later changes of `mUsers`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you simply need to add `mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` after `mUser.add(user);`
and even though the second method you used work fine, it's not the right way to do it, because that way you're specifying the adapter, setting the layout manager and setting the adapter for the recyclerView every time the data in the firebase changes